# Automatic Data Transfer to DAX

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm new in this so please pardon me for such a basic question.

I'm trying to pass some dates as filters to a measure.

I have a simple measure that counts opened items "last week".

The DAX I used:

```
OpenedLastWeek = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table);Table[Created 
Year]=2018;Table[Created Week]=45)
```

But there should be a way to pass values to the DAX code to replace manually entered "2018" and "45".

I tried Date Tables, extra tables with dates in it... I'm just confused.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I would probably use variables.

```
OpenedLastWeek =
VAR CreatedYear = --<Desired Year Calculation>--
VAR CreatedWeek = --<Desired Week Calculation>--
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS(Table);
        Table[Created Year] = CreatedYear;
        Table[Created Week] = CreatedWeek
    )
```

Basically, you define the week and year how you'd like and then pass those variables into the `CALCULATE` function.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. It solved my problem.

For this case, I tried variables before but I was getting wrong results. I guess that was because I was using "CountA()" instead of "Countrows()".

Thanks again.

Have a nice day,
Eld